# Getting webdriver exception: unknown error: unhandled inspector error...cannot navigate to URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using:

```
driver.get(“www.google.com”)
```

The script is not running from this line of code

And if i use:

```
driver.get(“https://www.google.com”)
```

It start working

Can anybody please help me out why it is working with https and not working without https?

Answer (score 1):

It is inbuilt implementation of Method `get();` and `navigate().to();` which work on HTTP GET request.

This is Declaration By method itself:

> Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using
> an HTTP GET operation, and the method will block until the load is
> complete. This will follow redirects issued either by the server or as
> a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. Should a meta-redirect
> "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout
> is over, since should the underlying page change whilst your test is
> executing the results of future calls against this interface will be
> against the freshly loaded page.
>
> Parameters: **url** The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL

***However When we use same string in Browser and it works. Because Browser has it default HTTP protocol and based on that if we don't text http:// or https:// it automatically convert String in to URL.***

Here transformation made via get(); method to Browser, and As declared by method it needs URL and not String. Thus it retrieve this Exception.